# GLSL Shader - 2D Rim Lighting Effect

Tags: 2d, glsl, shader, gradient, lighting

How can I create a gradient like the one seen in the image below using GLSL?

[image: Color Gradient]

What is the best method for achieving a smooth transition from opaque at the edges of the polygon being drawn to transparent at its center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image you referred to is achieved through what is called [distance transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform). It is a very useful and common operation widely applied in image processing, computer vision and robot path calculation, etc. What it does is for each pixel of a image, compute the 2D Euclidean distance from the pixel to the nearest edges of the polygon. The output is an image whose pixel value indicates the minimum distance. To visualize the results, we map the distance to gray scale. Particularly, in your reference image, the ridge with bright white has the largest distance to the boundary while the dark area contains much smaller values because they are very close to the polygon boundary.

In terms of implementation, a brutal force approach is to draw a 2D image you want to transform, and in the fragment shader, compute the distance from current fragment position to every edge of a polygon and output the minimum value to an framebuffer. The geometry information of the polygon can be stored in another texture. Eventually, you ends up with a 2D texture whose pixel value encodes the shortest distance to the edges of the polygon.
You can also find this common transform implementation in [OpenCV library](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/opencv/opencv_distance_transformation.htm).